# Prediction when survey subsets create dramatically smaller Ns

Tags: prediction, survey, missing-data

Suppose you want to predict an outcome using a sample whose N is...

- 10,000 based on most demographic variables
- 9,000 based on Survey Question 1
- 3,000 who answered "Yes" to Question 1 and thus were given Question 1A
- 700 who answered "Yes" to Question 1A and thus were given Question 1B
- 4,000 who answered "Yes" to Question 2 and thus were given Question 2A
- 600 who answered "Yes" to Question 2A and thus were given Question 2B

What methods, if any, have you found that are successful/worthwhile/practical ways of pulling all such information into a single model?

Comment: How is the "outcome" related to these subsets?

Comment: Every person has a Y value.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, there are 2 challenges in your data

1. *1000 missing value for question 1.* There is a whole literature on how to handle missing values in regression. [Statistical Analysis with Missing Data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471183865) by *Little* and *Rubin* is a very good reference for this topic. I think this is a minor issue for you.
2. *conditional branching in survey design*. I think this is your main problem. I am not sure if there is any statistical model that can handle this. What I usually do in practice is to combine multiple questions. For example, suppose your outcome $Y$ is a numerical scale of depression level and you have the following questions:

a) What is your gender?

b) If female, do you have a new born at home?

Let's say a mother with a new born is often associated with higher chance of depression. What you really need is a binary variable, which equals 1 if the respondent is a mother with new borns and 0 otherwise. However, you don't want to directly ask this question as you will lose many other useful information such as gender(and it is really a strange question and will confuse many!).

So what I would suggest you to do is to go through your survey and think about defining explanatory variables that have direct causal relationship with your outcome. This is often called data *pre-processing*, sth. I consider far more useful than using complicated statistical models.

Peter

Comment: Your part 2 of the answer is good.